# Windows Service SQL timeout exception

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008, windows-services

I have a Windows service which continuously each 10 seconds queries the SQL Server database table, and I also have a web site which also queries the same database table after 25 seconds.

After some time I get exception - `server timeout exception has occurred`. I went through stack-overflow site and has done the changes to SQL configuration settings but still I got the same exception. What to do?

**Stack Trace**

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoExecuteReader(DbCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior cmdBehavior)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteReader(DbCommand
>   command)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.CommandAccessor`1.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>         at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Message.Dispatch(Object target, Boolean fExecuteInContext)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Comment: Show us the full stack trace, and exception message, to start with.

Comment: You need to determine where this happening. Is it the connection, is it a transaction, command etc. use some logging to determine where the error is and post the exception trace. That should give you some clues as to what needs adjusting. As it stands your question is like mind reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show me the code! timeout exception usually are because you don't close the database connection.

try add the code in the final of algorithm

```
if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
```

If you use to EnterpriseLibrary, try add more time to commandTimeOut

```
DbCommand dbcommand = database.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_TheStoredProcedureName");
dbcommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
```

Comment: I am using the enterprise library and using DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase() method i am getting the database and executing the stored procedure against it. so need to close connection?

Comment: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @RaviKhapate: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.